# How can I debug a C program installed using guix?

Tags: gdb, guix

I installed flatpak using guix, but it segfaulted on startup. I wanted to debug it, but guix installs a wrapper script for flatpak, so I get this error when trying to run it under gdb:

```
"/home/user/.guix-profile/bin/flatpak": not in executable format: file format not recognized
```

and I tried to edit the wrapper script to call gdb, but this wrapper script is not even editable by root, because it is owned by root and has read-only permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy the script to your current working directory:

```
cp /home/user/.guix-profile/bin/flatpak .
```

Mark it as writable:

```
chmod +w flatpak
```

Edit the script with your favourite text editor, to replace the string `exec -a` with `exec gdb --args`.

And finally, run it with any arguments you provided before, when it misbehaved:

```
./flatpak remote-add flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

In this particular case, this wasn't immediately super-useful, because a [debug symbol output](https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Installing-Debugging-Files.html#Installing-Debugging-Files) hasn't been built for this package. But at least I could get a backtrace out of gdb.